# Java - Buffer - My Code skips the last Line of a TextFile when reading

Tags: java, file, buffer

im Trying to read a TextFile of Numbers on each Line into an ArrayList.
When i execute the following Function, it always Skips the last Element.
can somebody help me out ? cause i dont get the Problem here, since it reads til the Buffer is empty, he should stop when the FileEnd is reached, correct ?

```
    List<Double> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
    StringBuilder oneLine = new StringBuilder();

    try (SeekableByteChannel byteChannel = Files.newByteChannel(Paths.get(fileName))) {

        while (byteChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {

                char c = (char) buffer.get();

                if (c == '\r') {
                  //Skip it
                }
                if (c == '\n') {

                    System.out.println(oneLine.toString()); //Test Output to see what he got
                    lines.add(Double.parseDouble(oneLine.toString().replace(',', '.')));
                    oneLine.setLength(0);
                }
                else {
                    if (c != '\r') {
                        oneLine.append(c);
                    }
                }

            }
            buffer.clear();
        }

        System.out.println("Anzahl zeilen: " + (lines.size()));
        System.out.println("Finished");

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("The File that was defined could not be found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lines;
}
```

the TextFile with one Number on each Line:

```
999973
22423
999974
999975
999976
999977
573643
999978
999979
999980
999981
34322
999982
999983
999984
999985
999986
999987
999988
3
67
84,000
7896575543
8.0
100001
9999991
8.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reach the end of the file and there is no line break at your end of the file, you will add the characters to the `StringBuilder` but never append it to the list. You can either add a newline to the end of your text file or call `lines.add(...)` just before you call `buffer.clear()`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked out my Problem! didnt notice that theres no \n at the end of File.